# Open-Source Alternative of Closed-Source Swarm Optimization

Tags: optimization, model, constraint

We are currently using a [closed-source software for model optimization](https://developer.datastories.com/sdk/apireference.html#module-datastories.optimization).

Since it is closed, we have no transparency into the underlying code, which therefore by definition makes it challenging to switch away from the software to open source alternatives. I would like to ask the community if they have any hints into what could be viable (Python or R) alternatives?

The link shared above to the optimization package consists of (but is not limited to) the following classes/methods:

`class datastories.optimization.pso.Optimizer`: *A model optimizer using the particle swarm strategy for identifying an optimum solution.*

Where you can optimize using one of three different methods:

- `maximize` *(Run the optimizer with the goal of maximizing the outputs (i.e., KPIs) of a given model)*
- `minimise` *(Run the optimizer with the goal of minimizing the outputs (i.e., KPIs) of a given model)*
- `optimize` *(Optimize an input model according to a given optimization specification)*

If the third method `optimize` is used, then more flexibility is available, and constraints and objectives can be grouped under:

`class datastories.optimization.OptimizationSpecification`: *Encapsulates a set of optimization objectives and constraints that can be used to configure an optimization analysis.*

Those constrains/objectives, being for example:

- `class datastories.optimization.AtLeast`: *Specifies an optimization objective or constraint by which a variable (or aggregation of variables) should be greater than a given reference value.*
- `class datastories.optimization.Minimize`: *Specifies an optimization objective by which a variable (or aggregation of variables) should have the smallest possible value.*
- `class datastories.optimization.Maximize`: *Specifies an optimization objective by which a variable (or aggregation of variables) should have the largest possible value.*

A full code example (taken from the docs) would look like:

```
model = Model("my_model.rsx")
spec = OptimizationSpecification()
spec.objectives = [
    Minimize('KPI_1'),
    Maximize('KPI_2')
]
spec.constraints = [
    AtMost('Input_1', 10),
]
optimizer = create_optimizer()
optimization_result = optimizer.optimize(model, optimization_spec=spec)
```

Comment: I only happen to know about R's "pso" https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pso/pso.pdf which upon first glance does not appear to natively support constraints. Is constrained optim important to your use cases?